# How to store in Redis sorted set with server-side timestamp as score?

Tags: redis

I want to use a sorted set to store objects using the redis-server timestamp as score.

I know I can use Redis Streams with `*` id, but Redis Streams have limitations, including I cannot edit the objects, I cannot use rank or lexicographical sorting, I cannot really delete objects in the middle, unions or intersects, etc.

I want to do this atomically, and use the redis-server timestamp so I can use multiple clients to `ZADD` without worrying about clock-sync.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use a Lua script:

```
local time = redis.call('TIME')
local ts = time[1]..string.format('%06d', time[2])
return redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], ts, ARGV[1])
```

Here we use Redis [`TIME` command](https://redis.io/commands/time). The command returns:

- unix time in seconds
- microseconds

So we can concatenate these two and use a microsecond-timestamp. We need to zero-pad the microseconds part.

Since sorted sets are good with integer values up to 2^53, our timestamp is safe all the way up to the year 2255.

This is Redis-Cluster-safe as we store in one key. To use multiple keys, make sure to land them on the same node using [hash tags](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags) if you want to compare timestamps.

You can modify the script to use lower than microsecond resolution.

Here the `EVAL` command, simple pass key and value as arguments, no need to create the sorted set before hand:

```
EVAL "local time = redis.call('TIME') local ts = time[1]..string.format('%06d', time[2]) return redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], ts, ARGV[1])" 1 ssetKey myVal
```

As always, you may want to [load the script](https://redis.io/commands/script-load) and use [`EVALSHA`](https://redis.io/commands/evalsha).

```
> SCRIPT LOAD "local time = redis.call('TIME') local ts = time[1]..string.format('%06d', time[2]) return redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], ts, ARGV[1])"
"81e366e422d0b09c9b395b5dfe03c03c3b7b3bf7"
> EVALSHA 81e366e422d0b09c9b395b5dfe03c03c3b7b3bf7 1 ssetKey myNewVal
(integer) 1
```

A note on Redis version. If you are using:

- Redis Version before 3.2: sorry, you cannot use `TIME` (non-deterministic command) and then write with `ZADD`.
- Redis Version greater than 3.2 but < 5.0: Add `redis.replicate_commands()` on top of the script. See [Scripts as pure functions](https://redis.io/commands/eval#scripts-as-pure-functions)
- Redis 5.0 an up: you are good.