# How to unset a bit in a redis bitset when a corresponding status is considered 'off' after a time of inactivity?

Tags: redis

I find it very easy to count number of active connections using

```
redis_sip = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0)
redis_sip.setbit(skey, 1, 1)
redis_sip.setbit(skey, 2, 1)
redis_sip.setbit(skey, 3, 0)
redis_sip.setbit(skey, 4, 1)
print(redis_sip.bitcount(skey)) # shows me 3 connections
```

But for this to work I need to be able to set a TTL for each individual bit.

i.e. when a remote agent makes a connection, I can set the bit to 1. If bitwise expiry is supported, then the bit will be flipped after a length of inactivity.

Is it doable at all in Redis? If not, what is an alterantive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO, you cannot expire a bit.

Instead, you can only expire a key. So in order to achieve your goal, when a connection established, you can set a key with a timeout. When you want to get the total number of connections, use the `DBSIZE` command.

```
// agent 1 establishes a connection, set a timeout of 60s
SET 1 1 EX 60
// agent 2 establishes a connection, set a timeout of 60s
SET 2 2 EX 60
/// agent 1 closes the connection
DEL 1
// total connections
DBSIZE
```

Also, you should be careful with `SETBIT` command. If an agent with a large id, say, 100000000, establishes a connection, when setting the corresponding bit, Redis needs to allocate lots of memory, and might block for a while. See the [doc](https://redis.io/commands/setbit) for detail.

Comment: DBSIZE may not work for me because I will insert keys for other purposes. But thanks for the great answer.

Comment: You can use a database only for this purpose, see [SELECT command](https://redis.io/commands/select)

Answer (score 3):

As noted, Bitmaps do not support bit-level expiry. In fact, none of the core Redis data structures provide nested-element expiry.

An easy alternative would be to use Sorted Sets. For each new connection, [`ZADD`](https://redis.io/commands/zadd) it as a member with a score that is the current timestamp (epoch). Then, in order to obtain a count, do a [`ZREMRANGEBYSCORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyscore) from '-inf' to the current time minus your "TTL" - this will "trim" the zset to include only non-expired connections. Lastly, you can call [`ZCARD`](https://redis.io/commands/zcard) to obtain the cardinality/count of members.

Comment: Here [how to store in sorted set with server-side timestamp as score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846503/how-to-store-in-redis-sorted-set-with-server-side-timestamp-as-score)