# Elasticache / Redis Timestamp of new data

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

Does Elasticache store the time when a data is added to the cache? I want to filter data on my cache based on the time it was added but I can't find a clear answer if this information is stored in Elasticache automatically or if I have to add this information (timestamp) manually for each data inserted in the cache?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't filter data by time on Redis, do you want to filter by exact time or by range?

Comment: yes by the exact time that data was added

Comment: So you should be able to encode this data on the client perhaps part of the key

Comment: Or you might want to check RediSearch module

Answer (score 0):

Neither Redis nor ElastiCache's Redis-compatible service store the timestamp automatically.

This would be inneficient as many use causes don't require it, so it's a client application implementation detail.

You may use a sorted set to store this information, so you can query for date ranges. And you can use Redis server time automatically if you use a Lua script. See [How to store in Redis sorted set with server-side timestamp as score?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846503/how-to-store-in-redis-sorted-set-with-server-side-timestamp-as-score).

This is particularly important if you have multiple nodes connecting, as they may have clock differences.